# Signing an adobe air application with an spc file

Tags: air, digital-signature

I recently purchased a digital certificate from GoDaddy to sign an adobe air application.  GoDaddy, and probably some of the other CAs out there, deliver their certificates as SPC files.  However, most of the information about compiling and signing an air application assumes you have a p12 file.  I spent a while figuring out how to deal with this issue and thought it'd be good to share the process with the SO community.  I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to coming up with the correct method was understanding that a p12 file is a keystore - not just a certificate.  A keystore contains the key and the certificate.  When signing an adobe air app, you need to provide a keystore and not just a certificate.  So, let me begin from the top.

**Step 1**: Create a keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias codesigncert -keypass <yourkeypwd> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=displayname,O=companyname,C=US,ST=state,L=city" -keystore codesignstore -storepass <yourstorepwd>
```

**Step 2**: Create a certificate request

```
keytool -certreq -v -alias codesigncert -file mycsr.pem -keystore codesignstore
```

**Step 3**: Purchase a certificate from a CA using the CSR created in the previous step.  In my case, I downloaded the certificate as an SPC file.

**Step 4**: Add the certificate to your keystore

```
keytool -import -keystore codesignstore -storepass <yourstorepwd> -alias codesigncert -file mycert.spc
```

**Step 5**: Currently your keystore is a java key store (JKS).  Convert this to PKCS12

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore codesignstore -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore codesignstore.p12
```

**Step 6**: Sign your app

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore codesignstore.p12 -storepass <yourstorepwd> -keypass <yourkeypwd> <name of output file> application.xml <path to root dir>
```

I think it's probably also possible to skip step 5 and perform step 6 using the JKS keystore.  I didn't confirm that this works, however.

Comment: These instructions are very similar to these instructions from [godaddy](http://support.godaddy.com/help/4780).